# Concatenate datasets

Tags: dataset

I have multiple `Dataset`s that have a common data structure, e.g.:

```
Dataset1 = T (K) | B (T) | R (Ohm)
             1   |    1  |   1
             1   |    2  |   2

Dataset2 = T (K) | B (T) | R (Ohm)
             2   |    1  |   3
             2   |    2  |   4
```

I cannot figure out how to append the rows together from the datasets to get one large dataset like:

```
Dataset3 = T (K) | B (T) | R (Ohm)
             1   |    1  |   1
             1   |    2  |   2
             2   |    1  |   3
             2   |    2  |   4
```

I tried the `Append` function, but that does not seem to work. I'm sure there is something silly that I'm not getting.

Comment: Have you tried `Join[]`?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @J.M. - `Join[]` works! I figured that it was simple. If you put an answer to this question I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Join` will do the trick:

```
{dataset1, dataset2} =
  {{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 4}}} // Map[Dataset]
```

[image: pair of datasets]

```
Join[dataset1, dataset2]
```

[image: joined dataset]