# How to Join a list of Datasets

Tags: dataset

I have a an arbitrary number of ".wl" files to import, say 4~7 at any given time, that come in as `Datasets`. [This old thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123382/concatenate-datasets) does what I want for two datasets, but I'm having trouble extending it to an arbitrary number. I've tried `Join` and `Union` and both just return the same number of datasets, instead of one big one that I can start to analyze. I'd prefer not to hardcode a solution suggested in the thread for 4 or 5 files. What do people do in these situations to generalize?

```
l = {"data/PermitData-0612.wl", "data/PermitData-201547.wl", "data/PermitData-203002.wl", "data/PermitData-112098.wl"}

files2join[l_List] := Module[{var},
  var = Import[#] & /@ l;
  Join[var]
  ]
```

Comment: This is possibly dependent on the structure of your data. It would be good to have a glimpse of the contents of those files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using join on its own you could use the Apply function with both the Join function and list of data sets as parameters. For example:

```
files2join[l_list]:=Module[{var},
   var = Import[#]&/@l;
   Apply[Join,l]
]
```

Comment: I need to remember all the different ways `Apply` works.

Comment: Apply applies a function (the first parameter) to the second argument. If the second argument is a list, it splits the list and supplies each element in the list as a separate parameter in the function. For example Apply[f, {a, b, c}] = f[a,b,c]

Comment: (+1) you could also use `Join@@l`.